# Getting Runtime error while making API using YOLOV4-Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

Trying to create a API using yolov4-pytorch but facing error

**RuntimeError: shape '[256, 384, 3, 3]' is invalid for input of size 767781**.

Using yolov4-tiny with pretrained weights

**yolo.py file**

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from utils import *
from Darknet import Darknet


def process(uploads_dir, output_dir, filename):

    # Set the location and name of the cfg file
    cfg_file = './cfg/yolov4-tiny.cfg'

    # Set the location and name of the pre-trained weights file
    weight_file = './weights/yolov4-tiny.weights'

    # Set the location and name of the COCO object classes file
    namesfile = 'data/coco.names'

    # Load the network architecture
    m = Darknet(cfg_file)   #

    # Load the pre-trained weights
    m.load_weights(weight_file)

    # Load the COCO object classes
    class_names = load_class_names(namesfile)

    # Set the default figure size
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [24.0, 14.0]

    # Set the NMS threshold
    nms_thresh = 0.6

    # Set the IOU threshold
    iou_thresh = 0.4

    # Set the default figure size
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [24.0, 14.0]

    # Load the image
    img = cv2.imread(uploads_dir + '/' + filename + '.jpg')

    # Convert the image to RGB
    original_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    # We resize the image to the input width and height of the first layer of the network.
    resized_image = cv2.resize(original_image, (m.width, m.height))

    # Set the IOU threshold. Default value is 0.4
    iou_thresh = 0.4

    # Set the NMS threshold. Default value is 0.6
    nms_thresh = 0.6

    # Detect objects in the image
    boxes = detect_objects(m, resized_image, iou_thresh, nms_thresh)

    # Print and save the objects found and their confidence levels
    objects_count, objects_confidence = print_objects(boxes, class_names)

    # Plot the image with bounding boxes and corresponding object class labels
    plot_boxes(original_image, boxes, class_names, output_dir, filename)

    return objects_count, objects_confidence
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_cors import CORS
from yolo import process
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint
from Darknet import *

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
uploads_dir = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'uploads')
output_dir = os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'output')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    try:
        os.mkdir(uploads_dir)
        os.mkdir(output_dir)
    except:
        pass

    file = request.files['file']
    if not file:
        return {'error': 'Missing file'}, 400

    now = datetime.now()
    filename = now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + "_" + str(randint(000, 999))
    file.save(os.path.join(uploads_dir, secure_filename(filename + '.jpg')))
    objects_count, objects_confidence = process(uploads_dir, output_dir, filename)

    response = {
        'objects_count': objects_count,
        'objects_confidence': objects_confidence,
        'filename': filename + '.jpg'
    }

    return jsonify({"data": response}), 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Iam using this repo https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4, I have renamed **tool>darknet2pytorch as Darknet**

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4/issues/138) help you?

Comment: it is giving me error : **RuntimeError: shape '[256, 384, 3, 3]' is invalid for input of size 767781**, regarding which only I have asked

Comment: Put all the stacktrace here. Not just the last line. Because the problem is very likely in your code not the YOLOV4